# Accessing movieclips with linkage property getting undefined

Tags: actionscript-3

This is only happening in Windows and not in the osx flash player. I'm getting undefined property (referenceerror 1065) for most my movieclips in my library that I'm adding through actionscript using linkage. I'm creating new instances so I don't know why this is happening. Is there something I should be doing other than creating the linkage name?

I should also mention that I'm adding movieclips from the library to my classes that are movieclips.

Could it be an issue of my classes not being in the right place? I notice movieclips that aren't being used but with linkage names are throwing an error.

When I try to export as .app or .exe it gives me this error: No libraries were linked as Runtime Shared Libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out using TFL type textfields causes these weird errors. I just switched them to Classic and everything started working again.

Answer (score 0):

try using the getDefinitionByName("linkage")

or try to create a whole new file , the problem will be fixed